# Infotips Partially Hidden by the Window Edges When Selecting Files at the Ends

Tags: window, usability

Is there a hack that can prevent infotip popups jumping out of the visible area of the window when we select a file that is close to the edges?

I remember this was not a problem in WindowsXP (like so many other things), as the infotip popup always popped into the visible area of the window, even if the object was partially covered by some window border. Now in Windows 10, anyone who needs to be guided by infotips for some specific work loses a lot of time with scrollbars to view the entire information near the edge.

[image: Screen shot of windows 10 screen. Has a mix of irfanview and word icons. One of the icon has a tooltip that is partially covered by the taskbar.]

Comment: I'm not quite parsing what an infotip is - mind adding a screenshot with what this is exactly? If its a popup sort of thing win-printscreen would help loads

Comment: Thanks for instructions. A screenshot is worth a thousand words.

Comment: The bit at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, can you reproduce this?

Comment: Oddly enough, no. But I have a rather specific setup so... maybe its just me

Comment: Can someone else reproduce this situation, please? I remind you that the problem only occurs when using the directional keys and not the mouse. It seems a usability Windows error because I've tested it on several clean systems and the problem is the same.